# Get environment variables for Gradle projects in idea intellij 14 (OSX Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, gradle, global-variables, environment-variables

This question is extended from this question.  The top solution is not valid for Yosemite anymore. Could someone suggest a way to fix this.

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/588442#588442)

Because of this I cant even import my project to Idea Intellij 14...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the env vars are not accessible when an application is run from spotlight.

When I ran intellij from the command line, this problem was solved.

If you still want to run intellij from command line, wrap idea in a bash script. This will cause it to spawn from the command line itself.